# How do I make this program to list out if I have entered two consecutive zeros?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   int A[20], i, k;
   cout << "Write 20 random numbers: "<<endl;
   for(i=0; i<20; i++){
      cout << "A[" << i << "]: ";
      cin >> A[i];
   }
   k=0;
   if (i+1 == k){
      cout << "The program has two consecutive zeros";
   }
   else if (i+1 != k){
      cout << "The program doesn't own two consecutive zeros";
   }
   char ch1;
   cin>>ch1;
   return 0;
}
```

This is my code but I don't know how to configure out the if to show me a message first, if there are two zeros, and second if there aren't. If there are, I need to make it so the numbers on which these zeros are shown. I'm a student please help, I really have no idea how to do it

I did it for the most part. Thank you everyone for your help! What's left now is to make it so it shows to which respective numbers the zeros are. How do I do that? I did as varleti suggested but it only shows 20 and 21

Comment: you will have to count the zeros somewhere.

Comment: Besides actually having to count the zeros, the condition `i+1 == k` will never be true since you just before the check set `k` to zero.

Comment: I'm really bad at this I have no idea how to do it

Comment: As for your problem, do you have to check for *only* two zeros in a row, or two *or more*?

Comment: Only two consecutive zeros. It says "Write a program, which decides if there are two consecutive zero elements in the massive, and puts out the numbers in which these zeros are", not sure if I translated it right because I'm not an Native English speaker.

Comment: tip: start with detecting if there is at least a single zero in the input

Comment: Then a follow-up question, should the sequence `000` be counted once or twice, or not at all?

Comment: I don't know how to detect that.. I'm pretty bad at programming I don't know why I chose this subject now in HS. Also for Joachim, I think that it should be counted once, although I don't think that's the point, I only need to show if it can detect elements if I type in two separate zeros, like

Comment: A[1]: 446 A[2]: 386 A[3]: 45345 A[4]: 0 A[5]:0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a loop that you use to collect the data.

```
cout << "Write 20 random numbers: "<< endl;
for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
    cout << "A[" << i << "]: ";
    cin >> A[i];
}
```

You have collected the data into a 20 element array `A[20]`.

You need to walk through the array again and test the values for 2 consecutive zeros.

```
two_zeros = 0;
for(i=1; i<20; i++) {  // Note, starting from element [1]
    if( A[i] == 0 && A[i-1] == 0 ) { // Test this and previous element for zeroness
        two_zeros = 1;
    }
}

if( two_zeros == 1 ) {
    cout << "The program has two consecutive zeros";
} else {
    cout << "The program doesn't own two consecutive zeros";
}
```

Comment: the problem is that we don't use the true or false functions :/, but yes that would be correct

Comment: Instead of `true` and `false`. 

`two_zeros = 1`

`two_zeros = 0`

Comment: oh by the way, how do i i take out the numbers in which these zeros were, like perhaps they were on a[4] and a[5], how do i make it so it shows that it was on those?

Comment: Please this after the `two_zero` check.

`cout << "Zeros detected at position " << i << " and " i + 1 << endl;`

Comment: It always shows that they are detected at 20 and 21

Comment: I can't figure it out

Answer (score 2):

See this code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int A[20], i, k;
    cout << "Write 20 random numbers: "<<endl;
    for(i=0; i<20; i++){
    cout << "A[" << i << "]: ";
    cin >> A[i];
    }

    int count = 0;      /* To count number of consecutive zeroes */
    int flag  = false;  /* check wheather consecutive zeroes are found or not */
    for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
        if(A[i] == 0) {
            count++;
            if(count == 2) {
                flag = true;
                cout << "The program has two consecutive zeros" << endl;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            count = 0;   
        }
    }

    if(flag == false) {
        cout << "The program doesn't own two consecutive zeros";   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Let me know, if having any doubt regarding anything.

Comment: Do you think it can be done without the flag, false, break and count function? We haven't learned those yet and I think it would be weird.

Comment: Yes, few of them can be avoided, but all of them i not sure about that. See the answer written by my friend @varleti. he has used only `two_zeros` as flag to trigger the presence of the *consecutive zeroes*.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any array, you only need to remember whether the last number you read was zero.

```
int main ()
{
   bool last_zero = false;
   bool two_zeros = false;
   cout << "Write 20 random numbers: "<<endl;
   for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
       int x = 0;
       cin >> x;
       if (x == 0)
       {
           if (last_zero)
           {
               two_zeros = true;
           }
           last_zero = true;
       }
       else
       {
           last_zero = false;
       }
   }
   if (two_zeros){
      cout << "The program has two consecutive zeros";
   }
   else {
      cout << "The program doesn't own two consecutive zeros";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int A[20], i, k=0;
    cout << "Write 20 random numbers: "<<endl;
    cout << "A[0]";
    cin >> A[0];
    for(i=1; i<20; i++)
    {
        cout << "A[" << i << "]: ";
        cin >> A[i];
        if( A[i] == 0 && A[i-1] == 0 )
        {
            cout << "The program has two consecutive zeros";
            k=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(k==0)
        cout << "The program hasn't two consecutive zeros";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
for (int j = 0; j<20 - 1; j++)
{
    if (arr[j] == 0 && arr[j + 1] == 0)
    {
        count++;
        break;
    }
}
if (count == 1)
{
    cout << found;
}
else
    cout << not found;
```

Comment: can you please give some explanation with your code ?

Comment: in the above code where ever the two consecutive zeros are found the loop will end and count value will be 1 and out of the loop you just have to check if the two zeros are found or not with the help of count